# Java - reading data from website requiring login

Tags: java, authentication, web

I'm basically trying to use Java to read some data from my school's website (homework assignments, which lessons I have and when, etc.) for personal use. However, my school requires one to be logged in to access this information.

Could anyone point me in the right direction for logging in with code and accessing this information?

Thanks,
Mike.

Comment: What form of authentification? POST? .htacces?

Answer (score 2):

The Apache has a API for http client simulating.

Link: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out how the server handles logins. What authenticationer it used: cookies, url session id, etc.
Then you can send the server a login http form submit (as you would have done manually) and save the authenticationer.
With the authenticationer you can then access the secured sites.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net), which is a programmatic web browser.

You tell it to load the authentication page, to fill the form with your credentials and to click on the submit button. The you click on links, just as you would do it with a real browser, but programmatically, using Java instructions.

And it even supports JavaScript, if necessary.